# Getting TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object for Flask(__name__) python3

Tags: python, flask, web-applications, typeerror, nonetype

I am getting "TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object" while trying to run the simple flask web application.

Code Snipet:

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def welcome_page():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/output', methods=['GET'])
def fetch_channel():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        channel_search = request.form.to_dict()
        channel_name = channel_search["search"]
    return render_template(
        'output.html', name = channel_name) 


if __name__ == '__main__ ':
    app.run()
```

Detailed error:

````
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2023.1.2\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_comm.py", line 1245, in do_it
    _typeName, val_dict = pydevd_vars.resolve_compound_variable_fields(self.thread_id, self.frame_id, self.scope, self.attributes, dbg.get_user_type_renderers())
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object```
````

Comment: in the first line of the code: `request` is not valid...

Comment: What action did you take to get the error?

Comment: @D.L what about that is not valid? That's how you import `request`

Comment: Please update your question to include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We need to see the HTML and/or JS for the page that calls the `/output` route.

Comment: I have used command "flask --app main.py run" to execute the code, Its working fine.

Previously I was trying the old method but in upgraded flask version that is not working.